# jQuery + Fancybox trigger error on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have this jQuery code on my page that works fine in Chrome, but I get and error on Internet Explorer 8 in the trigger('click') line

```
$('#btnd16').click(function(e){
    var iiid = $('#midet').val();
    $('#d16_midethistorial_id').val(iiid);

    //sumamos por ajax
    var $mivalor = $('#d16_midethistorial_id').val() 
    var $url = $('input#miruta').val(); 

    $.post($url, { midethistorial_id: $mivalor }, 
        function(data) { 
                $("#nirefancy").fancybox({
                'width'         : '90%',
                'height'    : '90%',
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
                'type'      :'inline',
                'autoDimensions': false,
                'autoScale' : false,
                        'scrolling' : 'no',
                'titleShow' : true,
            }).trigger('click');
    });

    return false
});
```

This is my html for fancybox:

```
<a href="{{ path('detformacion_play',{'id': detentrenamiento.detformacion.id }) }}"  id="nirefancy" style="display: none;">.</a>
```

I clicked in a butten and I insert some data throught ajax in the database, after that I want to open a fancybox. Like I said, it works on Chrome but not in IE8

any help or clue?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Off the top of my head, two possibilites:

1)    `'titleShow' : true,` <-- extra comma at the end of object IE interprets as Satan

2) Enclose your event handler in a document ready block:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnd16').click(function (e) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: It is almost definitely the extra comma.

Comment: walaaaaa! it is a extra comma! Now the page loads correctly but when I clicked I get an error on jquery-1.5.2.min.js line 16 carachter 14229. the $('#btnd16').click... it is into $(document).ready(function() { with another funcions: http://pastebin.com/5PmS5CNT

Comment: Try to narrow down the whereabouts of the problem and post another question please, it's far too intimidating like that :)